# How to query userlicences that have remaining licenses

Tags: c#

I need to identify licenses that have remaining licenses. 
Referring to [UserLicense object](http://%20developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/%E2%80%A6%20link), I need to write a query to retrieve license that returns where (TotalLicenses - UsedLicenses) > 0.

I am using .Net client and Api version 34.
Following query works for get all license, (Working)

```
var licenseQry = await client.QueryAsync<Object>("SELECT Id,Name FROM UserLicense");
```

But (Not working)

```
var licenseQry = await client.QueryAsync<Object>("SELECT Id,Name,TotalLicenses FROM UserLicense")
```

does not work. Throws an error sating invalid column.

Am I missing something?

This question is a follow up question from [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102596/add-new-user-page-does-not-show-salesforce-user-license-in-the-drop-down).

Comment: May be this will help [count remaining license](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/getting-remaining-licenses-of-customer-portal-using-apex)

Comment: That one is based on apex. I am using the REST api client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got that same error message when I tried to query that field through the REST api as well:

```
$  curl https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,TotalLicenses+FROM+UserLicense -H 'Authorization: Bearer
```

In the salesforce object reference guide, it mentions that:

> This field is available through the API Access to User Licenses pilot program. For information
>   on enabling this pilot program for your organization, contact Salesforce.

[image: screenshot]